# Cannot build custom Keras model with custom loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I encountered this problem after running through the VAE example in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models), which cannot be built before fitting it data.

Apparently, it draws the following error:
`` ValueError: Expected a symbolic Tensors or a callable for the loss value. Please wrap your loss computation in a zero argument `lambda`. ``

Here is a simple MWE:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class Test(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, input_dim=784, name='test', **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.dense1 = layers.Dense(input_dim)
        self.dense2 = layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='relu')

    def call(self, inputs):
        y1 = self.dense1(inputs)
        y2 = self.dense2(inputs)
        loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(y2)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return y1

(x_train, _), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

test = Test()
test.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# test.build(input_shape=(64,784)) # --> gives error if uncommented.
# test.summary() # --> gives error if uncommented.
test.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)  # --> works well.
test.summary() # --> now it works fine.
```

If I remove the `self.add_loss` from the model, then the model can build properly.

Is there a way to `build` the model before `fit`ting it with custom loss `self.add_loss()`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known issue. Try to check it here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26274

Passing a sample input data on the test instance did the trick.
Adding the line below.

```
test = Test()
test(x_train[:1])
```

Here is a working code simulated using google colab

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class Test(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, input_dim=784, name='test', **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.dense1 = layers.Dense(input_dim)
        self.dense2 = layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='relu')

    def call(self, inputs):
        y1 = self.dense1(inputs)
        y2 = self.dense2(inputs)
        loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(y2)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return y1

(x_train, _), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)
test = Test()
test(x_train[:1]) # this will automatically build the model as per the error indicated. It seems that this is a bug
test.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
test.summary()
#test.build(x_train[:1]) # --> gives error if uncommented.
# test.summary() # --> gives error if uncommented.
#test.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)  # --> works well.
#test.summary() #
```